# PHP - Write selected checkboxes to a text file

Tags: php, checkbox, text-files, fwrite

What I want to do is write a bunch of songs that a user selects from a checkbox list to a text file.  The songs are listed in a text file, which is then opened and has its values stored into an array, and that array is used to make the checkbox list.  This is what I have so far.

```
<html>
<h1>Welcome to Zmzon.  Select songs below to add to your library.</h1>
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
/*Write song selections to myLibrary.txt file.*/
if(isset($_POST['songList'])){
    $addSongs = $_POST['songList'];

    $handle = fopen('myLibrary.txt', 'a');
    foreach($addSongs as $song){
        fwrite($handle, $song."\n");
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>

<form action="zmzon.php" method="POST">

<?php
/*Add contents of zmzonSongs.txt to array.*/
$songList = explode("\n", file_get_contents('zmzonSongs.txt'));

foreach($songList as $songs){
    echo "<br/><input type='checkbox' name='songList[]' value='$songs' />$songs<br>";
}
?>
<input type="submit">
</form>
<a href="ztunes.php">To zTunes</a>
</html>
```

I've looked around everywhere and I'm still struggling with this.

Comment: I can't figure out how to write what the user has checked from the song list into a text file.  The songs listed need to be written into that file (we'll call it myLibrary.txt), not just whether the box was checked or not.

Comment: have you tried using `fwrite` ?? see [here](http://www.php.net/fwrite)

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work.  I was watching a video that was explaining how to do this but since not all of the songs will be checked and each song is different, I wasn't sure what variable names went where and I didn't know if I needed a foreach statement.  This is what I was using.  http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=11&number=79  In addition, this video focuses on user text input, not checkboxes.

Comment: put the rest of the code and modify your question be accurate on what we are trying to solve

Comment: I added the code that wasn't working.

Comment: `$name` seems to be undefined variable and code in the `if` branch is never reached. Also `fwrite` line contains this `$name` variable.

Comment: @doc has a point , i guess `$name` is equivalent to `$songs`?

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo.  It should be fixed now.

Comment: So there is another problem. You refer to a key named `songs` in `$_POST` array, while you checkbox is named `songList`. Take a look at 
Banukobhan Nagendram's answer.

Comment: I was testing the code he provided and I'm seeing the checkboxes and everything on the page display as normal (nothing would appear with my old file handling code in use), but nothing is being written to the myLibrary.txt file.  I created it ahead of time in the hopes of being able to use 'a' instead of 'w' but I'm now wondering if that's the problem.

Comment: Add line `var_dump($_POST);` in your code, mark some boxes, then submit form and post the results of `var_dump`.

Comment: These are the results of var_dump:  array(3) { [0]=> string(15) "Tool - Parabola" [1]=> string(21) "Tool - Rosetta Stoned" [2]=> string(12) "Tool - Jambi" }

Comment: @user3308219 are these results of `var_dump($_POST);` or `var_dump($_POST['songList']);`?

Comment: @doc The output of var_dump($_POST) is as follows: array(1) { ["songList"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(15) "Tool - Parabola" [1]=> string(21) "Tool - Rosetta Stoned" [2]=> string(12) "Tool - Jambi" } }

Comment: Can you update your question and post the **actual** code you are using?

Comment: @doc Updated to current version.

Comment: O.K. I have copied your code and it actually works for me... Maybe your script does not have permissions to write to `myLibrary.txt` file. You may try to delete this file, write something without dealing with form. Also turning on `display_errors` directive in `php.ini` or via `ini_set()` and setting `error_reporting(E_ALL);` may help recognize the problem, if they are off.

Comment: @doc It was the permissions.  This stupid school has so many idiotic hoops and hurdles to go through just to get assignments like this done that I envy the dead.  Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Hah, I regret that I haven't asked about permissions earlier, because suspected it from the beginning. Yet number of typos in your code made me think this is not an issue ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do the following in the zmzon.php file

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['songList'])){
    $listOfSongs = $_POST['songList'];

   $fp = fopen('myLibrary.txt', 'w');
    foreach ($listOfSongs as $song) {
        fwrite($fp, $song.'\n');
    }
    fclose($fp);
}

?>
```

The above process is used to receive the song list and store it in file 'myLibrary.txt'.
you can include the above part in your existing zmzon.php file

Comment: I tried out the code and the page shows up again (it wouldn't even display the checkboxes with what I originally had), but I took a look at the text file (myLibrary.txt) and it was empty.

Comment: @user3308219 have you checked any checkbox? Add line `var_dump($_POST['songList']);` to see what is being sent within form. HTML checkboxes are specific - if they are not checked then no value is being sent.

Comment: I tried checking every available box, then just a few.  Nothing happened with either submission.

Comment: @Banukobhan Nagendram you should probably add new line character after each song title in `foreach` loop. Also to make code secure one should filter input provided by `$_POST`. Otherwise `myLibrary.txt` may be filled with weird data and this can lead to serious security issues.

Comment: I attempted to place his code outside of the form action block but this didn't fix anything.  I'm not even sure if it needs to go inside that block or not.

Comment: Did you print and tested you have received the songList in the zmzon.php file?

Comment: @doc, Ya. Sorry, I forget add the new line character. Thanks to remind me.

Comment: `'\n'` should be in double quotes -> `"\n"`, otherwise it will print literally `\n` to the file.